# CSS Display table add space between separating border

Tags: css

In a markup with `display: table` I'd like to separate some rows with a dividing line.

```css
.table { 
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-row {display: table-row; }
.table-cell {display: table-cell; width: 50%}
.border-between {border-top:1px solid;}
.padding-t {padding-top: .5rem}
.padding-b {padding-bottom: .5rem}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell padding-b">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row border-between">
    <div class="table-cell padding-t">3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">4</div>
    <div class="table-cell">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row  border-between">
    <div class="table-cell">5</div>
    <div class="table-cell">5</div>
  </div>
   <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">6</div>
    <div class="table-cell">6</div>
  </div>
   <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">7</div>
    <div class="table-cell">7</div>
  </div>
   <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">8</div>
    <div class="table-cell">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While this works without problem when setting `border-collapse: collapse;` I'm looking for a nice and clean way to add some vertical space before and after the line as I did in my example between line 2 and 3. I would favor a solution without adding extra markup and modifying some cells for providing padding. Thanks for pushing me into the right direction!

Comment: If it is a table then use a `<table>`. You don't win anything by creating a table with divs and setting e display to table. If it's no table then why do you need display table?

Comment: @cloned thanks. the advantage of display table is formatting the content with media queries on smaller screens.

Comment: You can use media queries with tables too.

Comment: so to come back to my problem you would suggest to use tables with paddings?

Comment: does my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the `height` of every cell thereafter align the contents(numbers) in the center will also make it looks like an expected result you want

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}

.border-between {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

.m {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell m">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell m">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell m">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell m">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row border-between">
    <div class="table-cell m">3</div>
    <div class="table-cell m">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell m">4</div>
    <div class="table-cell m">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row  border-between">
    <div class="table-cell m">5</div>
    <div class="table-cell m">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell m">6</div>
    <div class="table-cell m">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell m">7</div>
    <div class="table-cell m">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell m">8</div>
    <div class="table-cell m">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gad This would make each line 50px height. I would search for a clean solution to only have padding before and after the line

Comment: you mean a CSS built in property!! I don't think there is another clean way than trick but you can put a bounty on your question may be you'll get it